# Regex keeps returning null

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to parse a string using regex. The result I get is a multidimensional array that has no contents. It is returning the correct number of child arrays but with no results. Below is PHP result, regex code, and string that is passed in. Can someone show why the result is null? Here is an example to show it does not work http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d9dead4e23b5784a9a5ba7a098a958edb7113f62

The result I get

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )
```

Regex code

```
$content = $fetcher->fetchFile($directory.'/'.$fileName);
        preg_match_all('/\[@style\](.*?)\[@end\]/s', $content, $matches);
        print_r($matches);
```

The string being parsed

```
ul.nav > li > a {
  padding: 0 10px; }
/**
 *  @style
 */
button {
  background: blue !important; }
/*  @end */
/**
 *  @style
 */
span {
  background: blue !important;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px; }
/* @end */
```

Comment: Your regex has `[` and `]` around `@style` and `@end`, remove them. See https://regex101.com/r/wxPQex/1

Comment: Why use tags when you can just capture all the styles, with this `/([-0-9a-zA-Z,.:\[\]()\s#>]+\{[^}]+\})/`  [Test it!](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/86cbdb95bb78490bb2c94108a8c6999cf04e5f2c)

Comment: I don't want to just catch the styles, I want to catch the comments as well

Comment: Removing [] did work either

Comment: here is an example to show it does not work http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d9dead4e23b5784a9a5ba7a098a958edb7113f62

Comment: I just ran your sandbox with `preg_match_all('/@style(.*?)@end/s', $input, $matches);` and `$matches[0]` contains all the styles with comments e.g. `[0] => @style */ button {  background: blue  important; } /*  @end`  If that's not what you want you should update the question with your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using:

```
preg_match_all("/\/\*\*\s*\*\s*\@style\s*\*\/(.*?)\/\*\s*\@end\s*\*\//s", $input, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /**
 *  @style
 */
button {
  background: blue !important; }
/*  @end */
    [1] => /**
 *  @style
 */
span {
  background: blue !important;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px; }
/* @end */
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it needs to return the comments around  css